# How to put padding/spacing in-between list view item and scroll bar [Android]

Tags: android

I have a ListView where I want to put spacing/margin/padding in-between list view items and the scroll bar.

```
:ListView:
+------------------------+------------+----------+
|List Item 1             |            |          |
+------------------------+            |          |
|List Item 2             |----Space---|  Scroll  |
+------------------------+            |    Bar   |
|List Item 3             |            |          |
+------------------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the padding to your list item layouts?

Comment: yes i have tried it, but still scroll thumb appears next to list items there is no padding in-between.

Comment: And you do put the padding in the layout for your list item? That is, not the list.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I have found the solution:
Set scroll bar style as `outsideInset` and then add scroll bar padding to right.

```
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
```

That's it!

Comment: Adding padding to the right changes the touch target width of all the children as well. I you don't care about your design, you can use this.

Comment: Nice. If you want scrollbars working just like on iOS you should use `outsideOverlay`.

Comment: Wow! I'm looking for this for several hours! Thanks for this! I fix my issues perfectly with this!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted teh same with my TableLayout. Padding helped me out. For yuo it should be :

```
android:paddingRight="10dip"
```

YEs. If you add ListView in ScrollView, your listView will scroll with ScrollView.

Try this. Hopefully it will give u your desired results.

Comment: padding does not set padding inbetween scroll thumb and list item. it doe not work for me. :(

Comment: Try adding paddingLeft in your scrollview. Padding leaves soem space between both the components. To see the results more appropriately initially give higher "dip" value. Also set background color of ListView, so when the padding is added you will see the additional space between list & scrollview. It worked out with me TableLayout inside Horizontal & Vertical scrollviews. Try out.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

1º You load your content view, with 3 vertical layouts

2º Then, use 3 fragments that you want, in different xml, and load the content in each one.

3º Set the margin between layouts.

You have a good example [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Is there any easy solution which can be implemented using xml code only.

Comment: I dont think it possible, because you must use a setcontentView, and use the xml structure, to combine them, you must use fragments. Its the same, just the differents parts are in differents xmls.