# Set divider for horizontal Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Is it possible to make a space between horizontal Listview items?
I try this for listview.
`android:divider="#ffff00" android:dividerHeight="10dp"`

It's working fine in listview. but I want add divider between horizontal Listview items. How to rectify this Problem?. Share Your Idea?

Comment: is your is customized ,means using baseadapter??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984313/spacing-between-listview-items-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160239/how-to-put-padding-spacing-in-between-list-view-item-and-scroll-bar-android

Answer (score 0):

Set border around your list items in xml file or add custom view as below:

```
<View 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:width="1dp"
    android:background="#ffff00"
/>
```

Comment: i have border for my listitem.i want to have some space between the list item

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by horizontal list view in Android?

If it is customised list then add a view betwwen two items and set the backgroundcolor for the view.

Answer (score 0):

With all respect to **@Mihir Shah**, updating his answer to match your requirement.

Set border around your list items in xml file or add custom view as below:

```
<View 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:width="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

This will provide space you require.